# How to display all added subject marks or total marks of student in array

Tags: php

I am getting all student and their subject marks in foreach loop and at last I am adding in loop.

What I want is all total marks of student in an array.
1. I am getting the all the subjects marks according subject id. 
2. Fetching the student data from database and their marks using foreach loop.
3. Adding the marks and getting total marks of all subjects. 
4. Return an array of all total marks .

This is what I tried :

```php
foreach ($result_detail as $key => $value) {
    $total_marks += $value['get_marks'];
    $total_rank = $value['total_rank'];

  for ($i=0; $i < count($value) ; $i++) { 
            $c = array();
      $grades = array();
       $c[$i] = $total_marks;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then .. you should set variable as array and append values to it:

```
<?php

$total_marks = []; // Set default values to make sure it won't throw error for undefined variable below in code
$total_rank = 0; 

 foreach ($result_detail as $key => $value) {
   $total_marks[] = $value['get_marks']; // append values to array
   $total_rank += $value['total_rank']; // add rank to current rank
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($total_marks);
echo $total_rank;
```

Notice that I also changed `$total_rank` now I add rank each iteration instead of overwriting the value.

Comment: i got the total marks of all student but i want to store only total marks in array

Comment: `i want to store only total marks` what is this ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: i defined one variable as $total_marks, now from database i am getting $value['get_marks'] and in total marks i done the summation of student marks according to subject marks .. now for all different student i am getting different total marks, so i am getting multiple total marks that i want to store it in array.

Comment: Can you provide some input (not all data just part of it) and exepcted output in your question ?

Comment: subject 1 subject 2  subject 3  total_marks 
  15            59              23            97
  15          15            15            45
  0              0                0              0                                                                      
that last column total marks i want as array but every time the index of that is array(0)

Comment: i want array(97,45,0) like this i want value of total marks in back end but its assigning new array for each total_marks and index is 0

Comment: From where you know which mark for which subject is ? Add this to your question, please.

Comment: through subject id i mentioned there

Comment: Just use `var_dump($result_detail);` over your foreach and add part from result on your screen in your question, please.

Comment: is it necessary to display  that

Comment: Yes if you want complete answer, which fits your desire output : )

Comment: my output is coming properly just in back-end i want total marks as array thats it